# Grafana "Node Exporter Full" Dashboard shows no data after Import

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to import Node Exporter Full Dashboard from here: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860

But when I import the dashboard, it shows nothing.

[image: Grafana Dashboard after Import]

My Prometheus.yml file has following config:

[image: prometheus.yml config file]

DataSource is tested & working fine:
[image: Prometheus DataSource]

I'm getting all the metrics from node_exporter when I "curl http://localhost:9100/metrics"
Also, the same metrics are visible in Prometheus.

What is the problem in Grafana Import? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Grafana dashboard, 1860, makes use of node_exporter metric named 'node_uname_info'. Whenever you load the dashboard, it'll find the instances returned by node_uname_info metric and retrieve the data for that.

This particular metric is only available for node_exporter. For any other job, since this metric is not available, Grafana doesn't render any data because it didn't find any entry pertaining to 'node_uname_info'.

In the list you've provided, only the last job seems like coming from node_exporter since it's deployed on its default port. You may want to check what's the metric value for node_uname_info you're receiving on 'localhost:9100'(based on your config) and then modify your Grafana query accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I get the same nothing. Removed it from our environment