# No panels/ dashboards showing in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I've imported the Node Exporter Full dashboard from https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860 and it seems to go ok but I can't see any panels.

[image]

This is part of my Prometheus.yml file

```
- job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'grafana'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:3000']
  - job_name: 'alertmanager'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9093']
  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100']
  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8000']
  - job_name: 'forethought'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:80']
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

I just can't see what I'm doing wrong....I've been Googling and checked that I have actually installed node exporter and that the service is actually running.

My versions are  node_exporter-0.17.0.linux-amd64  and prometheus-2.7.1.linux-amd64

I found this which is exactly the same ([Grafana "Node Exporter Full" Dashboard shows no data after Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102670/grafana-node-exporter-full-dashboard-shows-no-data-after-import)) ..but there was only one answer (which I didn't understand) and it received no upvotes

any help gratefully received..even if it's just hints and nudges.....

Comment: The dashboard info states that: `Since revision 16, for prometheus-node-exporter v0.18 or newer. Since revision 12, for prometheus-node-exporter v0.16 or newer`. You probably installed the latest revision and if so, then it is not compatible with the ancient node-exporter that you got from Ubuntu repos. Try [revision 15](https://grafana.com/api/dashboards/1860/revisions/15/download), the last one before some metric names were changed.

Comment: ok thanks....I saw that but didn't really understand it tbh..I'll try that